# recursive method keeps referencing the same local variable

Tags: c#, recursion

I have a recursive function that goes like this (I rewrote the problematic part for the purpose of this question):

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var stuff = Foo(new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 });
        foreach (var item in stuff)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ListToString(item));
        }
        /*
         * Expected:
         * [2,3,4,5]
         * [1,3,4,5]
         * [1,2,4,5]
         * [1,2,3,5]
         * [1,2,3,4]
         * 
         * Actual:
         * [1,2,3,4,5]
         * [1,2,3,4,5]
         * [1,2,3,4,5]
         * [1,2,3,4,5]
         * [1,2,3,4,5]
         */
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Foo<T>(IEnumerable<T> list)
    {
        var result = Enumerable.Empty<IEnumerable<T>>();
        int count = list.Count();
        if (count % 2 == 0)
        {
            result = result.Append(list);
            return result;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            result = result.Concat(Foo(list.Where((_, j) => i != j)));
        }

        return result;
    }

    public static string ListToString<T>(IEnumerable<T> list)
    {
        var res = new StringBuilder();
        res.Append("[");
        res.Append(String.Join(", ", list));
        res.Append("]");
        return res.ToString();
    }
}
```

I added the expected and actual results to the code above, I hope that makes it clear. In short, the method either prints the whole input list (if it's of even length), or calls itself with a list that got one element removed (=> its length is an even number again).

I really think it's something with the `result` variable and that it somehow gets overwritten with every call, but I did try renaming it (one path got `result`, the other worked with `result2`), and the result stayed the same. Also, the debugger shows that with every iteration in the for loop the result value gets overwritten, and it basically does `[[1,3,4,5]].Concat([[1,3,4,5]])` (`i = 1` in this example). I would think it'd do `[[2,3,4,5]].Concat([[1,3,4,5]])` in this example (first and second iteration of the for loop).

So, there's something I'm not seeing here.

Comment: sorry, but I can' t see any recusion.

Comment: @Serge: `result = result.Concat(Foo(list.Where((_, j) => i != j)));`

Comment: Your sub-sequences capture the loop variable `i`. That means that with each iteration of the loop, _they change_. At the end, the loop variable is set to `6` and so no filtering is done. You need to copy the loop variable value into a local variable declared in the loop, and use _that_. See duplicate.